# Showing the DB credentials in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm new to laravel (v5.3)

I got this issue by accident, (I still in development mode)

I ran my app and its worked correctly, but when the DB was turned off, I get this error

```
in Connector.php line 119
at PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=social', 'root', '', array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in Connector.php line 119
at Connector->createPdoConnection('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=social', 'root', '', array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in Connector.php line 56
at Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=social', array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => '3306', 'database' => 'social', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => '', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => true, 'engine' => null, 'name' => 'mysql'), array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in MySqlConnector.php line 24
at MySqlConnector->connect(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => '3306', 'database' => 'social', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => '', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => true, 'engine' => null, 'name' => 'mysql')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 100
```

I'm surprised when I see the DB credentials.

Does this error stay like that in production mode?

Is there any way to stop showing DB connection info?

Comment: disable debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `APP_DEBUG` in your production `.env` to `false`.